# Mobile version of website doesn't show at mobile phone(HTML & CSS)

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a problem with open my website on mobile device, but it's works when I just change the size of my Chrome window of my laptop.

```css
    
    @media screen {
    body{ 
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color:darkgray;
    font-family:  Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body{ 
    background-color: pink;
    color:black;
    font-family:  Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    }
```

```html
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="pac.css" media="screen" >
    <link media= "screen and (max-width: 480px)"  href="pac.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    
    </html>
```

Maybe someone knows what it can be, why it's not works on mobile.

Comment: you forgot to add meta tag for  responsive.. add this and try.. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

Try It Once .

Answer (score 1):

May be you forgot to add viewport meta tag, add following meta tag in you head section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Comment: then why don't you accept his answer , accept and upvote inspiring the developers who gave answer